# Permission issues when starting Windows Service using MSBuild Extension Pack

Tags: msbuild, windows-services, user-permissions

I have an MSBuild project file to deploy a windows service.

While trying to start the service after the files are copied over, the command returns the 
following error:

```
error : Start Service failed with return code '[2] AccessDenied'
```

I used the following ways to achieve this but all return the same error:

1. MSBuild ServiceController
2. MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService Exec Command="net
3. start $(WindowsServiceName)"

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running this command prompt in Administrator mode or not?

Comment: Are you able to post your code how u did it bcoz i had a same problem and solved it. Wondering if you are using the same code.